# Vundle can't install plugin

Tags: vim, vundle

I am trying to install rust.vim and I have followed the instructions to install Vundle and I added `Plugin 'rust-lang/rust.vim'` in my vim.rc file before `call vundle#end()` but when I try to load up Vim I get the following

```
Error detected while processing /Users/jordanbaron/.vim/bundle/newL9/plugin/l9.vim:
line   40:
E174: Command already exists: add ! to replace it
line   89:
E174: Command already exists: add ! to replace it
line  100:
E174: Command already exists: add ! to replace it
line  104:
E174: Command already exists: add ! to replace it
```

I hit enter and when I use `:PluginInstall' It says done with errors, here's what the log says:

```
[2017-03-14 17:16:10]                                                          |
[2017-03-14 17:16:10] Plugin file:///home/gmarik/path/to/plugin                |~                                                                             
[2017-03-14 17:16:10] $ git clone --recursive 'file:///home/gmarik/path/to/plug|~                                                                             
in' '/Users/jordanbaron/.vim/bundle/plugin'                                    |~                                                                             
[2017-03-14 17:16:10] > Cloning into '/Users/jordanbaron/.vim/bundle/plugin'...|~                                                                             
[2017-03-14 17:16:10] > fatal: '/home/gmarik/path/to/plugin' does not appear to|~                                                                             
 be a git repository                                                           |~                                                                             
[2017-03-14 17:16:10] > fatal: Could not read from remote repository.          |~                                                                             
[2017-03-14 17:16:10] >                                                        |~                                                                             
[2017-03-14 17:16:10] > Please make sure you have the correct access rights    |~                                                                             
[2017-03-14 17:16:10] > and the repository exists.                             |~                                                                             
[2017-03-14 17:16:10] >                                                        |~                                                                             
[2017-03-14 17:16:11]                                                          |~                                                                             
[2017-03-14 17:16:11] Helptags:                                                |~                                                                             
[2017-03-14 17:16:11] :helptags /Users/jordanbaron/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim/doc  |~                                                                             
[2017-03-14 17:16:11] :helptags /Users/jordanbaron/.vim/bundle/vim-fugitive/doc|~                                                                             
[2017-03-14 17:16:11] :helptags /Users/jordanbaron/.vim/bundle/L9/doc          |~                                                                             
[2017-03-14 17:16:11] :helptags /Users/jordanbaron/.vim/bundle/command-t/doc   |~                                                                             
[2017-03-14 17:16:11] :helptags /Users/jordanbaron/.vim/bundle/newL9/doc       |~                                                                             
[2017-03-14 17:16:11] :helptags /Users/jordanbaron/.vim/bundle/rust.vim/doc    |~                                                                             
[2017-03-14 17:16:11] Helptags: 6 plugins processed
```

Comment: Looks like there is some typo in your vimrc. Can you share your vimrc ? The problem command is 'Plugin file:///home/gmarik/path/to/plugin' that is causing problems.

Comment: gmarik is the original author of Vundle, this is no doubt a copy/paste issue of some sort.